# Word Size increase with size limit in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write some script that will allow the user to click on an object and each time they click it will increase in font-size by 1px.

It works fine until I try adding the while loop to add a size limit.

```
var fs = $(".word").css('fontSize');
$(".word").click(function() {
  while (fs <= "25px") {
    $(this).css('fontSize', (parseInt(fs) + 1) + 'px');
  }
});
```

Comment: `fs` never changes so `while` will never end. really makes no sense using `while` anyway for this

Comment: You're not recomputing `fs`.

Comment: just use `if` ...assuming your code worked it would change it to maximum right away

Comment: `while (fs <= "25px")` is absolutely wrong. You can increment / decrement a single _character_ of the ASCII table, but this absolutely will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/goxavokuciho/1/edit)

The reason your code doesn't work is about the condition. When you compare the value of string. Like `'44px' < '12px'` or `'44px' < '123px'`, it always **false**. 
**Pay more attention**
[the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons/359509#359509)

```
while (fs <= "25px")
```

change to:

```
while (parseInt(fs) < 25)
```

Everything is ok!

Comment: @self I have compared three tools to run web Server. http://jsfiddle.net/ and http://codepen.io/ and http://jsbin.com/. Finally, I found that JsBin is more quicly. Here is a article http://voidcanvas.com/jsbin-jsfiddle-or-codepen-which-one-to-use-and-why/rticle about reason.

Comment: @GarrettMaring If you agree, please click **correct answer**

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert but I believe the resulting while loop doesn't terminate. I guess the infinite loop just gets terminated at some point when it takes too much time.

Comment: @GarrettMaring You don't need the while loop at all. Using an if statement is enough, so: `if (parseInt(fs) < 25)`

Comment: Thank you all! It was a combo of two things as you guys pointed out.  I needed to do the comparison with a `parseInt(fs)` and each time is was clicked i need to redefine `fs` from the updated css.

Answer (score -1):

- You are comparing an integer with a string, so something like 12 <= "25px". What you should do is comparing 2 integers.
- You don't need a while loop here. You only have to increase the font size once per click, so one size check + increase is enough.
- You should store the increased value of `fs` back into `fs` or get the updated font size using `fs = parseInt($(".word").css('fontSize'))` in the click function.

So one possible solution is:

```
var fs = parseInt($(".word").css('fontSize'));
$(".word").click(function(){
    if (fs <= 25){
        fs++;
        $(this).css('fontSize', toString(fs) + 'px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using string comparisons instead of numeric.

```
var fs = +$('.word').css('fontSize'); //gets actual number
while(fs <= 25) { //compares numbers
    $(this).css('fontSize', fs + 'px'); //the '+' coerces to string
    fs++; //increment the iterator
}
```

Comment: This would get `fs` to 25 directly with one click. I don't think this is the behavior wanted.